# Objective C - How to instantiate a class saved as a variable

Tags: objective-c, class, instance

I am new to Objective C and I'm getting confused by this concept.

The following method is supposed to create instances of the class that is passed as a parameter and edit the instance's variables.

```
- (void) createObject:(Class)objecttype atPoint: (CGPoint)position {

    if ([objecttype isSubclassOfClass:[GameObject class]]){

        id theobject = [[objecttype alloc] init];

        theobject.x = position.x; //error
        theobject.y = position.y; //error
    }
}
```

I get an error message where indicated above :   `Property 'x' not found on object of type '__strong id'`

It seems like it should be simple, but I don't understand whats wrong.

Answer (score 6):

The dot notation will not call methods on objects of type `id`.

Change that allocation line to:

```
GameObject *theobject = (GameObject*)[[objecttype alloc] init];
```

Note that, because of the `isSubclassOfClass:` conditional, the above cast is precisely correct.

Comment: You should accept answers when you think you've found the best answer. People will be more inclined to help you in the future

Comment: In my case I have a `Class<MyProtocol> myClass` object but I can not instantiate it. `[[myclass alloc] init]` says No known class method for selector 'alloc'.